# Почему не генерируются числа во всем диапазоне?

Tags: c++

Должны же от 1000 до 10000, а они постоянно рядом.

```
    srand(time(0));
    cout << 1000 + rand() % 10000;
```

Comment: `rand() % 9001 + 1000;`? Надеемся, что `srand(time(0));` не находится в цикле вместе с выводом.

Comment: В любом последующем вызове цифра получается рядом с предыдущей (5151,5171...)

Comment: А хочется чтобы ну например 2011,7891,5444,1966...

Comment: Нет не в цикле, у меня просто вызывается функция

Comment: Это случаем не очередной фейл с многократным вызовом srand? Кроме того, диапазон тут не от 1000 до 10000, а от 1000 до 10999.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу неравномерности — вам кажется, это рандом. Вы находите закономерности, там где их нет.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    for (auto i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        std::cout << (rand() % (10000-1000+1) + 1000) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да он просто srand в цикл вставил, вот и все...

Comment: Ну может быть) Хотя, тогда было бы не 5151, 5171, а 5151, 5151 =)

Comment: Неа srand у меня к циклу никогда не был привязан

Comment: Ваш результат воспроизвести не удается. Покажите его где-то на ideone, как этот: https://ideone.com/9KpgoN

Comment: @BlackMagic, к чему srand привязан? когдато ты его же вызываешь? может всего один раз вначале программы но сразу несколько копий программы запускаешь?